# How to point Springdoc Swagger UI to my own YAML file instead of the auto-generated one?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have created a Spring Boot RESTFul microservice and for the documentation, I have created a swagger.yaml file but I don't know how to run that file. To create the swagger.yaml file, I have used OpenAPI Specification. I know that we have a Swagger UI feature to work with but I want to run my own created swagger.yaml file just because to get rid off lots of annotations.

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.1

info:
title: Static Data Manager
description: This is Static data Manager Swagger
version: 1.0.0

servers:
- url: http://localhost:8184/
  description: Generated server url

tags:
- name: LookupController
  description: API of Lookups
- name: LookupDataController
  description: API of Lookups Data
- name: LookupLangController
  description: API of Lookups Lang
- name: TranslationController
  description: API of Translations

paths:
/translation:
get:
  tags:
    - TranslationController
  operationId: fetchAll
  summary: Get All Translations
  parameters:
    - name: text
      in: query
      required: false
      schema:
        type: string
    - name: code
      in: query
      required: false
      schema:
        type: string
    - name: lang
      in: query
      required: false
      schema:
        type: string
    - name: pageable
      in: query
      required: true
      schema:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pageable'
  responses:
    "200":
      description: OK
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/PageTranslationModel'
    '401':
      description: Unauthorised
    '403':
      description: Forbidden
    '404':
      description: Invalid input
put:
  tags:
    - TranslationController
  operationId: update
  summary: Update a Translation
  requestBody:
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/TranslationModel'
    required: true
  responses:
    "200":
      description: OK
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/TranslationModel'
    '401':
      description: Unauthorised
    '403':
      description: Forbidden
    '404':
      description: Invalid input
post:
  tags:
    - TranslationController
  operationId: save
  summary: Save a Translations
  requestBody:
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/TranslationModel'
    required: true
  responses:
    "200":
      description: OK
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/TranslationModel'
    '401':
      description: Unauthorised
    '403':
      description: Forbidden
    '404':
      description: Invalid input
/translation/{transId}:
get:
  tags:
    - TranslationController
  operationId: fetch
  summary: Fetch a Translation
  parameters:
    - name: transId
      in: path
      required: true
      schema:
        type: integer
        format: int64
  responses:
    "200":
      description: OK
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/TranslationModel'
    '401':
      description: Unauthorised
    '403':
      description: Forbidden
    '404':
      description: Invalid input
delete:
  tags:
    - TranslationController
  operationId: delete
  summary: Delete a Translation
  parameters:
    - name: transId
      in: path
      required: true
      schema:
        type: integer
        format: int64
  responses:
    "200":
      description: OK
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            type: object
    '401':
      description: Unauthorised
    '403':
      description: Forbidden
    '404':
      description: Invalid input

/lookupsLang:
get:
  tags:
    - LookupLangController
  operationId: fetchAll_1
  summary: Get All Lookup Langs
  parameters:
    - name: text
      in: query
      required: false
      schema:
        type: string
    - name: lang
      in: query
      required: false
      schema:
        type: string
    - name: sorting
      in: query
      required: false
      schema:
        type: string
    - name: pageable
      in: query
      required: true
      schema:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pageable'
  responses:
    "200":
      description: OK
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/PageLookupLangModel'
    '401':
      description: Unauthorised
    '403':
      description: Forbidden
    '404':
      description: Invalid input
put:
  tags:
    - LookupLangController
  operationId: update_1
  summary: Update a Lookup Lang
  requestBody:
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/LookupLangModel'
    required: true
  responses:
    "200":
      description: OK
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/LookupLangModel'
    '401':
      description: Unauthorised
    '403':
      description: Forbidden
    '404':
      description: Invalid input
post:
  tags:
    - LookupLangController
  operationId: save_1
  summary: Save a Lookup Lang
  requestBody:
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/LookupLangModel'
    required: true
  responses:
    "200":
      description: OK
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/LookupLangModel'
    '401':
      description: Unauthorised
    '403':
      description: Forbidden
    '404':
      description: Invalid input
/lookupsLang/{lookupId}:
get:
  tags:
    - LookupLangController
  operationId: fetch_1
  summary: Fetch a Lookup Lang
  parameters:
    - name: lookupId
      in: path
      required: true
      schema:
        type: integer
        format: int64
  responses:
    "200":
      description: OK
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/LookupLangModel'
    '401':
      description: Unauthorised
    '403':
      description: Forbidden
    '404':
      description: Invalid input
delete:
  tags:
    - LookupLangController
  operationId: delete_1
  summary: Delete a Lookup Lang
  parameters:
    - name: lookupId
      in: path
      required: true
      schema:
        type: integer
        format: int64
  responses:
    "200":
      description: OK
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            type: object
    '401':
      description: Unauthorised
    '403':
      description: Forbidden
    '404':
      description: Invalid input

/lookupsData:
get:
  tags:
    - LookupDataController
  operationId: fetchAll_2
  summary: Get All Lookups Data
  parameters:
    - name: text
      in: query
      required: false
      schema:
        type: string
    - name: code
      in: query
      required: false
      schema:
        type: string
    - name: pageable
      in: query
      required: true
      schema:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pageable'
  responses:
    "200":
      description: OK
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/PageLookupDataModel'
    '401':
      description: Unauthorised
    '403':
      description: Forbidden
    '404':
      description: Invalid input
put:
  tags:
    - LookupDataController
  operationId: update_2
  summary: Update a Lookup Data
  requestBody:
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/LookupDataModel'
    required: true
  responses:
    "200":
      description: OK
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/LookupDataModel'
    '401':
      description: Unauthorised
    '403':
      description: Forbidden
    '404':
      description: Invalid input
post:
  tags:
    - LookupDataController
  operationId: save_2
  summary: Save a Lookup Data
  requestBody:
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/LookupDataModel'
    required: true
  responses:
    "200":
      description: OK
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/LookupDataModel'
    '401':
      description: Unauthorised
    '403':
      description: Forbidden
    '404':
      description: Invalid input
/lookupsData/{lookupId}:
get:
  tags:
    - LookupDataController
  operationId: fetch_2
  summary: Fetch a Lookup Data
  parameters:
    - name: lookupId
      in: path
      required: true
      schema:
        type: integer
        format: int64
  responses:
    "200":
      description: OK
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/LookupDataModel'
    '401':
      description: Unauthorised
    '403':
      description: Forbidden
    '404':
      description: Invalid input
delete:
  tags:
    - LookupDataController
  operationId: delete_2
  summary: Delete a Lookup Data
  parameters:
    - name: lookupId
      in: path
      required: true
      schema:
        type: integer
        format: int64
  responses:
    "200":
      description: OK
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            type: object
    '401':
      description: Unauthorised
    '403':
      description: Forbidden
    '404':
      description: Invalid input

/lookups:
get:
  tags:
    - LookupController
  operationId: fetchAll_3
  summary: Get All Lookups
  parameters:
    - name: lookupName
      in: query
      required: false
      schema:
        type: string
    - name: text
      in: query
      required: false
      schema:
        type: string
    - name: code
      in: query
      required: false
      schema:
        type: string
    - name: pageable
      in: query
      required: true
      schema:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pageable'
  responses:
    "200":
      description: OK
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/PageLookupModel'
    '401':
      description: Unauthorised
    '403':
      description: Forbidden
    '404':
      description: Invalid input
put:
  tags:
    - LookupController
  operationId: update_3
  summary: Update a Lookup
  requestBody:
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/LookupModel'
    required: true
  responses:
    "200":
      description: OK
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/LookupModel'
    '401':
      description: Unauthorised
    '403':
      description: Forbidden
    '404':
      description: Invalid input
post:
  tags:
    - LookupController
  operationId: save_3
  summary: Save a Lookup
  requestBody:
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/LookupModel'
    required: true
  responses:
    "200":
      description: OK
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/LookupModel'
    '401':
      description: Unauthorised
    '403':
      description: Forbidden
    '404':
      description: Invalid input
/lookups/{lookupId}:
get:
  tags:
    - LookupController
  operationId: fetch_3
  summary: Fetch a Lookup
  parameters:
    - name: lookupId
      in: path
      required: true
      schema:
        type: integer
        format: int64
  responses:
    "200":
      description: OK
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/LookupModel'
    '401':
      description: Unauthorised
    '403':
      description: Forbidden
    '404':
      description: Invalid input
delete:
  tags:
    - LookupController
  operationId: delete_3
  summary: Delete a Lookup
  parameters:
    - name: lookupId
      in: path
      required: true
      schema:
        type: integer
        format: int64
  responses:
    "200":
      description: OK
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            type: object
    '401':
      description: Unauthorised
    '403':
      description: Forbidden
    '404':
      description: Invalid input

 components:
  schemas:
  TranslationModel:
    type: object
    properties:
      webId:
        type: integer
        format: int64
      clientId:
        type: integer
        format: int64
      text:
        type: string
      code:
        type: string
      lang:
        type: string
  LookupLangModel:
  type: object
  properties:
    webId:
      type: integer
      format: int64
    lookupDataId:
      type: integer
      format: int64
    clientId:
      type: integer
      format: int64
    text:
      type: string
    lang:
      type: string
    sorting:
      type: integer
      format: int32
LookupDataModel:
  type: object
  properties:
    webId:
      type: integer
      format: int64
    clientId:
      type: integer
      format: int64
    lookupId:
      type: integer
      format: int64
    startDate:
      type: string
      format: date-time
    endDate:
      type: string
      format: date-time
    description:
      type: string
    text:
      type: string
    code:
      type: string
    lookupName:
      type: string
    sorting:
      type: integer
      format: int32
    strAttribute1:
      type: string
    strAttribute2:
      type: string
    strAttribute3:
      type: string
    intAttribute1:
      type: integer
      format: int32
    intAttribute2:
      type: integer
      format: int32
    intAttribute3:
      type: integer
      format: int32
    status:
      type: integer
      format: int32
    lookupLangModels:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/LookupLangModel'
LookupModel:
  type: object
  properties:
    webId:
      type: integer
      format: int64
    clientId:
      type: integer
      format: int64
    startDate:
      type: string
      format: date-time
    endDate:
      type: string
      format: date-time
    lookupName:
      type: string
    status:
      type: integer
      format: int32
    lookupDataModels:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/LookupDataModel'
Pageable:
  type: object
  properties:
    offset:
      type: integer
      format: int64
    sort:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/Sort'
    unpaged:
      type: boolean
    paged:
      type: boolean
    pageSize:
      type: integer
      format: int32
    pageNumber:
      type: integer
      format: int32
Sort:
  type: object
  properties:
    unsorted:
      type: boolean
    sorted:
      type: boolean
    empty:
      type: boolean
PageTranslationModel:
  type: object
  properties:
    totalPages:
      type: integer
      format: int32
    totalElements:
      type: integer
      format: int64
    size:
      type: integer
      format: int32
    content:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/TranslationModel'
    number:
      type: integer
      format: int32
    sort:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/Sort'
    numberOfElements:
      type: integer
      format: int32
    first:
      type: boolean
    last:
      type: boolean
    pageable:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pageable'
    empty:
      type: boolean
PageLookupLangModel:
  type: object
  properties:
    totalPages:
      type: integer
      format: int32
    totalElements:
      type: integer
      format: int64
    size:
      type: integer
      format: int32
    content:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/LookupLangModel'
    number:
      type: integer
      format: int32
    sort:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/Sort'
    numberOfElements:
      type: integer
      format: int32
    first:
      type: boolean
    last:
      type: boolean
    pageable:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pageable'
    empty:
      type: boolean
PageLookupDataModel:
  type: object
  properties:
    totalPages:
      type: integer
      format: int32
    totalElements:
      type: integer
      format: int64
    size:
      type: integer
      format: int32
    content:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/LookupDataModel'
    number:
      type: integer
      format: int32
    sort:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/Sort'
    numberOfElements:
      type: integer
      format: int32
    first:
      type: boolean
    last:
      type: boolean
    pageable:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pageable'
    empty:
      type: boolean
PageLookupModel:
  type: object
  properties:
    totalPages:
      type: integer
      format: int32
    totalElements:
      type: integer
      format: int64
    size:
      type: integer
      format: int32
    content:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/LookupModel'
    number:
      type: integer
      format: int32
    sort:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/Sort'
    numberOfElements:
      type: integer
      format: int32
    first:
      type: boolean
    last:
      type: boolean
    pageable:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pageable'
    empty:
      type: boolean
```

Comment: You can refer to this <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55112759/how-do-i-make-swagger-ui-use-a-yaml-json-rather-than-having-to-put-annotations-o> there is great explanation

Comment: What do you mean by "run"? Generate API documentation? Create a server based on this API definition? Integrate this file somehow with your existing source code?

Comment: @Helen when i hit the URL like localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html, it generates a swagger documentation page which is non documented. I want to run my own swagger.yaml file instead of the pre generated UI given by the OpenApi Specification.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your custom yaml/json file is saved under resources/static folder.
Then set `springdoc.swagger-ui.url` property to your file name.

example

structure : resources -> static -> swagger-config.yaml

property : `springdoc.swagger-ui.url=/swagger-config.yaml`

Comment: doest it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui` dependency and [springdoc](https://springdoc.org/#what-is-a-proper-way-to-set-up-swagger-ui-to-use-provided-spec-yml) recommendation doesn't work, make sure that static files are servable. One of the ways how to fix this is below.

```html
@Bean
RouterFunction<ServerResponse> staticResourceRouter(){
     return RouterFunctions.resources("/swagger*", new ClassPathResource("static/"));
}
```