# Spring + OpenAPI3 getting Swagger 404 when using static openApi.yaml file

Tags: swagger-ui, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have a simple spring application setup, with an openAPI dependency, in my pom file I added:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

and I put a sample *openapi.yaml* file in the static resource folder, I then followed the instructions in the document:

1. Turn off auto-generation in the project property file:

   ```
   springdoc.api-docs.enabled=false
   ```
2. Put your yaml file in *src/main/resources/static* such as *src/main/resources/static/myApiFile.yaml*
3. Set the swagger-ui URL for the file:

   ```
   springdoc.swagger-ui.url=/myApiFile.yaml
   ```
4. Enable the minimal beans configuration:

   ```
   @Configurationpublic class SpringDocsConfiguration {
   @Bean
   SpringDocConfiguration springDocConfiguration() {return new SpringDocConfiguration();}
   @Bean
   public SpringDocConfigProperties springDocConfigProperties() {return new SpringDocConfigProperties();}}
   ```

When I run the application and go to the URL: *localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html*, it shows that the .yaml file can not be fetched:

[image]

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.dao.diy</groupId>
        <artifactId>ADO-Diy</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

<!--    <groupId>org.dao.diy</groupId>-->
    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
    <name>backend</name>
<!--    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>-->


    <packaging>war</packaging>

<!--    <name>backend</name>-->
    <description>backend</description>


    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>-->
<!--            <scope>test</scope>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
      <finalName>ADO-DIY-TESTING</finalName>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>./src/main/resources/static/</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>../frontend/dist/frontend/</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>


        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

</project>
```

My debugging steps include:

1. Following the documentation
2. Googling for existing solutions
3. Changing file locations
4. Trying different configuration combinations

Comment: Hey, did you manage to get it working? For me it helped when I only did steps 2 and 3.

Comment: Thanks for asking Kajzer, unfortunately it still did not work for me...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use the following structure for your resources folder:

```
resources -> static -> myAPIFile.yaml
```

Found the answer here: [How to point Springdoc Swagger UI to my own YAML file instead of the auto-generated one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65612026/how-to-point-springdoc-swagger-ui-to-my-own-yaml-file-instead-of-the-auto-genera)