# How to initialize swagger from openapi resource file

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, springdoc

I'm using kotlin spring boot web mvc application. I've created an api-first file `openapi.yml` that contains api description. Also I've added required dependencies, like:

1. Gradle openapi generator plugin
   `id("org.openapi.generator") version "6.3.0"`
2. Openapi `implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:${libs.versions.openapi.get()}")`

I've successfully generated apis / model with gradle generator from my file, but I need to make it as a template for swagger.
I've reviewed all the springfoc's settings and it seems, that I can only forward a **generated documentation** with a `springdoc.swagger-ui.url` property.

Is there any way to initialized swagger from a `openapi.yml` file manually?

Comment: Does this answer your question -- [How to point Springdoc Swagger UI to my own YAML file instead of the auto-generated one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65612026/113116)

Comment: Not really so. I'm using springdoc, so it's a little different thing.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to find how to resolve this issue.

For `springdoc` the right way is described here:
https://springdoc.org/faq.html#_how_can_use_custom_jsonyml_file_instead_of_generated_one

My steps:

1. Add springdoc settings:

```json
springdoc:
  api-docs:
    enabled: false
  swagger-ui:
    url: /openapi.yaml
```

2. As it's written there - it's very important to place yaml file into proper location: `src/main/resources/static`
3. For multi-module projects api docs can be placed at root projects and then copied into mentioned above path with a custom gradle task, like:

```
register<Copy>("copyOpenApiDoc") {
        from(rootProjectOpenapiFolder.resolve("openapi.yaml"))
        into(buildDir.resolve("resources/main/static"))
}
```

Perhaps not a beautiful solution, but it works